# How can I provide my own login screen for Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently Spring Security is displaying this default login screen:

[image]

How can I configure Spring boot security so that I can use my own template so that I can customize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
          // other security settings...
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login.html")
          ;
    }
}
```